# Async task without waiting for the result

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got a Node.js / Express application where sometimes I need to perform a non critical async task that doesn't require waiting for the result (for example, a call to save some data in an analytics platform):

```js
router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
    criticalTask()
      .then(result => {
          res.json({success: true});
          nonCriticalTask();
      })
      .catch(next)
}
```

Is there a guarantee that the `nonCriticalTask()` gets executed completely without terminating it in the middle? Are there any restrictions on this?

Comment: If there are any exception/error happens in `nonCriticalTask()`, yes it will terminate in the middle. You have to handle it. But what you asked is holds. You are not waiting for the result to perform any other task. If anything inside `nonCriticalTask` is async, you will have the advantage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think would terminate it, can you elaborate on why you think it might not be called, or why it might not complete.

Comment: Specifically in our case, the `nonCriticalTask` involved making an HTTP POST request to an external service, and sometimes the TCP session was terminated in the middle of the call, without sending the full POST data (as per logs of this external service provider, which is Zapier if that matters). There was no indication in our server logs that anything was wrong. Once we switched to waiting for the result of `nonCriticalTask`, the issue was gone. So I'm trying to find some documentation on what is the expected behaviour.

Comment: hi @Anton did you find your answer? I have a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't find any documentation on this. After lots of experiments and logging, seems that `nonCriticalTask()` doesn't terminate and is executed by node and node doesn't exit if there are tasks still executing or handles are in use, e.g. DB connection is open.

So it seems to work for my `nonCriticalTask()` that does analytics. That being said, it's probably a bad design practice to rely on the node engine for anything critical running in the background like this, and other approaches should be considered, e.g. persistent queues.